# "Have you worked" vs. "Did you work" in a complex question in which both past, present and future events are involved

Tags: tense

> Shoe: Kitty, how many hours a day **did you work last week**  and when do you think you'll be exhausted? (1)
>
> Shoe: Kitty, how many hours a day **have you worked last week**  and when do you think you'll be exhausted? (2)
>
> Kitty: Really, Shoe, I've already exhausted myself, especially physically, and that's exactly why I want to suspend my work.

In Shoe's questions past, present and future events are mixed.

Which is the correct time frame,

> (1) "did you work", or (2) "have you worked"?

Answer (score 2):

Usage of Present Tense and Future Tense with Simple Past or Present Perfect doesn't really matter; what matters is whether the *confusing* verb will be in Simple Past or in Present Perfect.

To determine which tense will be used follow these simple steps:

> **1) Has the Time Period finished?** If yes- Simple Past, else- Present Perfect.
>
> **2) Is the information old?** If yes- Simple Past, else- Present Perfect.
>
> **3) Is the action time specific?** If yes- Simple Past (If it falls under **definite past**), else- Present Perfect.
>
> **4) Has the action finished?** If yes- Simple Past, else- Present Perfect. (Most important)
>
> This rule is mostly applied to see which tense is the most appropriate. If the result of the action still persists in the present, it is present perfect, otherwise it's Simple Past.

Example-

I *have lived* in California for five years. (Still living)

I *lived* in California for five years. (Don't live now)

In your cited example, from the context, it seems that the time period of Kitty's work hasn't finished yet and in the coming time, she is not going to work more for her fatigue and the ailment of the work has been added to her body making her exhausted when the speaker is speaking to her. So the actions (*being fatigued*) of her work still persists. So the most appropriate tense would be Present Perfect. Hence, your "Have you worked" would be the correct tense here.

Also note that, an additional "in the" before the week is required to make the time continuous as suggested by StoneyB. A mere "last week" means the week has gone past and the continuity of Kitty's work is not properly reflected. But if we add "in the" in front of week, it becomes continuous. So the proper way to put the sentence would be:

> Shoe: Kitty, how many hours a day *have you worked* **in the** last week and when do you think you'll be exhausted?

To read more, visit [Simple Past vs Present Perfect](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/simpas-preper) or [ELC study Zone](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/ppvpast.htm).

Comment: +0.95 Pr•Pf is exactly right, for exactly the reasons you give. But Pr•Pf forbids the use of adverbials which refer only to the past, so OP's *have you worked last week* is formally unacceptable. It needs to be something like ***in** the last week*, which embraces the immediate present; as you say, "the time period of Kitty's work hasn't finished yet".

Comment: So that means that OP's statement 1 is correct as written, but that statement 2 could be made to work if it were changed to "in the last week"- All of which I agree with. But that means that the "*hence your 'Have you worked' would be the correct tense here*" is actually incorrect.

Comment: @Jim, Is this comment meant for me or @StoneyB?

Comment: @StoneyB, How can an **in** make such a big difference? I am really surprised!

Comment: @Mistu4u It's as much the *the* as the *in*. Bare *last week* means the week before this week, a week which is "over and done with" and lies entirely in the past. ***The** last week* means the seven days leading up to and including the present moment, so it has the present reference required of adverbials in Pr•Pf clauses.

Comment: Also, that's the meaning of the "definite time" maxim (or as you put it, "specific"). It's not "definite-as-opposed-to-vague" time reference which prohibits  Pr•Pf, it's "definite-past-as-opposed-to-present" time reference&mdash;with "definite" in the sense of having a boundary (between past and present). I may quite properly say "I have been a father since 1:23 a.m. on September 10, 1990", because the "since" defines a timespan which culminates in the present moment.

Comment: @StoneyB, Okay.I would try to add your points as advised.

Comment: Hmmm, "how many days did you work last week?" is a perfectly grammatical question and exactly what you'd expect someone to ask the following Monday (of an employee, say). As you say the use of the perfect would imply leading up to the present, so it is the kind of question you imagine being asked at end of play on Friday (assuming a normal working week). Cf "what did you do in the war dada?". The context could be consistent with either situation.